# Add an extra \ in python winpaths

Tags: python, windows

Using python with windows I'm trying to get my program to see if `Dropbox.exe` exists if it doesn't nothing will happen if it does then the program will run. I used the print appdata as a debugging feature and this is what it prints: `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming`
and I think the problem is that it needs to print `C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\` so then I can add the last part as `\\Dropbox\\bin\\Dropbox.exe`

```
import winpaths
appdata = winpaths.get_appdata()
print appdata


try:
   with open('appdata\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe') as f: pass
except IOError as e:
   print 'dropbox cant be found'
```

Comment: [os.sep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep) provides the default separator for your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be using the appdata variable in your open:

```
with open(appdata + r'\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe') as f: pa
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should use forward slashes for paths as backslashes are used to escape special characters, and forward slashes will work fine, even under windows. Alternatively, use raw strings (`r"C:\some\path"`). For an example of why you should do this:

```
>>> print("\path\to\random")
andom   o
>>> print("/path/to/random")
/path/to/random
>>> print(r"\path\to\random")
\path\to\random
```

To do what you want, look at [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join the two parts:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("/path/to", "some/file")
'/path/to/some/file'
```

Note that I am using Linux, so this produces a linux-style path, however, under Windows it will adjust accordingly.

So in your case:

```
with open(os.path.join(appdata, 'Dropbox/bin/Dropbox.exe')) as f:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely to encounter bugs due to backslashes escaping characters in your string.  Use a raw string to prevent this:

```
with open(r'appdata\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe') as f:
```

Also, to add extra bits to pathnames, look at the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module, especially [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).